# Animate UINavigationController transition with blocks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, objective-c-blocks

Can anyone tell the block animation equivalent of this below code snippet?

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight 
           forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];

NextViewController *next = [[NextViewController alloc] 
           initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:next animated:YES];
[next release];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
NextViewController *next = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];

[UIView transitionWithView:self.navigationController.view 
                  duration:0.75 
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight 
                animations:^{
                 [self.navigationController pushViewController:next animated:NO];
                } 
                completion:nil];
```

Comment: Much easier solution for this than some of the other ways I have seen on stack. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
UIView: + (void)transitionFromView:(UIView *)fromView toView:(UIView *)toView duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```