# `pushViewController:animated:` with fade animation (animate transition only)?

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewcontroller, frame, transition

There a lot of similar questions with answers. For example:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838219/showing-pushviewcontroller-animation-look-like-presentmodalviewcontroller)

but almost all of them are unsuitable because I also want to perform something like this:

```
button1.frame = button2.frame;
button2.hidden = YES;
```

So if I use an example with `beginAnimations:` then I can see how button1 changes its frame (it moves while app perfoms a transition animation).

How to solve this issue? First of all should I set a button frame in another way or should I find another code for transition?

**EDITED**

Additionally I have found out that not all ways allow to show fade animation I need so I have edited my question a little.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? also consider using blocks instead of beginAnimations:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737461/animate-uinavigationcontroller-transition-with-blocks)

The best solution from it is animating way which works for my case.

The most strange thing is to disable view controller's own animation instead of its changing.